# Set of limit point is a closed set.

Tags: general-topology

Let $L$ be the set of limit points of set $A$. How do you show that the set $L$ is closed? Or, is this statement not necessarily always true?

Comment: What does $A$ lie inside?  A metric space, or any topological space?

Comment: You show that if $x$ is a limit point pf $L$ then it is also a limit point of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The following proof works if singletons are closed.

Let $x\notin L$.

Then an open set $U$ exists such that $\left(U\backslash\left\{ x\right\} \right)\cap A=\emptyset$.

Then $U\backslash\left\{ x\right\} $ is open and from $\left(U\backslash\left\{ x\right\} \right)\cap A=\emptyset$
it follows that $\left(U\backslash\left\{ x\right\} \right)\cap L=\emptyset$.

(This because for any $y\in U\backslash\left\{ x\right\} $ we have
open set $U\backslash\left\{ x\right\} $ with $\left(U\backslash\left\{ x\right\} \right)\cap A=\emptyset$,
showing that $y\notin L$)

Combined with $x\notin L$ we now have $U\cap L=\emptyset$, so for
$x\notin L$ we have found open set $U$ with $x\in U$ and $U\cap L=\emptyset$.

This can be done for any $x\notin L$ so allows the conclusion that $L$ is closed.