# Proving that there is no set with a certain given set of limit points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis

The first question asked of me was to construct a set of points with limit points being the integers. I came up with
$$A=\cup_{n=1}^\infty \{(n-1)+1, (n-1)+1/2,(n-1)+1/3+... \} \cup \cup_{n=1}^\infty \{-n-1,-n-1/2,-n-1/3,... \}$$
based on an example my instructor did.

The second question, which I am confused about, is: Prove that there is **no** set $A$ whose set of limit points is $$\{1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...,1/n,...\}$$ The hint for the second question is to understand why the first question works, but I don't see why on a deep level. **Please help me answer this second question and better understand the first.**

Comment: The second fails because if all the $\frac 1n$ are limit points, then $0$ must be a limit point.

Comment: @lulu What's the problem with 0 being a limit point?

Comment: It's not on the list.  If you add $0$ to the list, then you can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For every set $A$ it holds $A'' \subseteq A'$. Now if there exists a set $A$ with $A' = \{1/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ by the above $0 \in A'' \subseteq A'$, a contradiction.

Comment: Is $A'$ notation for the limit points of $A$?

Comment: @ExponentBOT Yes.

Comment: Where can I find a proof of "For every set A it holds A′′⊆A′"?

Comment: @ExponentBOT I suggest you try and prove it yourself. If you get stuck [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891006/set-of-limit-point-is-a-closed-set) is an MSE post about it

Comment: Okay, so the idea is that the set $A'$ of limit points (for any set $A$) is always closed, and hence it contains its limit points, i.e. $A'' \subseteq A'$.

Comment: @ExponentBOT Exactly. I don't know how familiar you are with topology but this result holds generally for $T_1$ topological spaces (ie singletons are closed). In the case of metric spaces, it's pretty trivial to prove it just by comparing the sequence characterizations for closed sets and limit points.